# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que una session expire en php?

Tags: session

¿Cómo puedo evitar que una sessión expire en php?
Estoy elaborando una página web simple donde el "Patron" se "logea" en un formulario simple donde tiene que poner un "password" que solo el sabe y entonces al capturarlo correctamente lo manda a otro página web donde los "empleados" puedan capturar su hora de llegada al trabajo, es importante que ellos "NO" puedan registrar su hora de llegada desde "otro" dispósitivo como su celular, etc, y para ello es importante que una sessión esté activa en la computadora donde se registran al llegar, para ello es muy necesario que la sessión que activó el "patrón" NO EXPIRE durante al menos unas 12 horas para que la pagina este disponible para los empleados.

No sé como lograr que no expire la sessión durante al menos 12 horas.
¿Alguna orientación?

Comment: Buenas, Iván, lo que planteas no parece corresponderse con el sentido y significado de una sesión en el protocolo HTTP, que es mantener los datos de un usuario a través de distintas requests que se hacen consecutivas en el tiempo. Un solo usuario, no un superusuario y sus subordinados y en un tiempo mucho más limitado del que tú planteas, además.

Comment: La password activa por 12 horas debería almacenarse en la BBDD y consultarse cuando el empleado registra su entrada. De forma totalmente independiente de la sesión inicial. Si los empleados solo pueden logarse desde un pc, debería controlarse la IP de ese elemento. Ya sea a nivel de administración de redes o a la hora de tratar la request.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
define('DURACION_SESION','43200'); //12 horas
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime",DURACION_SESION);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",DURACION_SESION);
ini_set("session.save_path","/tmp");
session_cache_expire(DURACION_SESION);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Aunque, para tu caso en concreto, le daría una vuelta a la propuesta de @RubioRic de gestionarlo a través de la IP del equipo del trabajo.